How do I attach a python debugger to a Gradio UI running on IntelliJ Jupyter?
I am running Gradio in an IntelliJ Jupyter plugin editor window. I have set a breakpoint in the chat function. I run the following code to start a Gradio interface in debug mode. The breakpoint I created is "Suspend: All", not "Suspend: Thread".
The breakpoints are not being hit.
How do I run Gradio so that my breakpoints are being hit?
gr.ChatInterface(fn=chat).launch(debug=True)

I am guessing the Gradio interface starts a separate process that is not captured by my debugging session?
